# Browse during test run

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the Webkit/Chromedriver in an otherwise standard Cucumber/Capybara-driven Rails application.

It works well, while the scenarios are running in non-headless-mode, I can see what the browser is doing.

It would help me a lot to be able to click around in the "driven" chrome at specific points of a scenario. For giggles I inserted a `byebug` in some step. At this point, the byebug console opens, Cucumber/Capybara obviously stop, and the chrome sits around waiting until I exit the byebug console.

If I then click in the chrome window, it hangs indefinitely. The reason is pretty clear => at this point in time, there is a request from chrome to my application-under-test, and because this is sitting in `byebug`, it can't handle the request.

What do I have to do to make this work (if possible at all)? I am familiar with the architecture of how all of this works (in normal operation, when Capybara or the Webkit are driving my chrome). But it would be so nice to just stop at some point in the scenario and click around myself, because then I could save myself a lot of time setting up the test data (including browser sessions and all that) manually. Note that `byebug` is not important to me, if there is some solution that I can execute inside a step, which makes Cucumber wait indefinitely and gives up the control to me, that would be perfectly enough.

Comment: i do this quite often, the trick is to put byebug or pry in the test. when execution halts, it's only the test-process that is blocked, you can interact with the website as usual, the entrypoint is `current_url`

Comment: @phoet: Funnily, I do seem to remember that it used to work for me as well, but in the last few days, whenever I tried what you (and I myself in the question) described, it does not work anymore.

Comment: This issue keeps popping up whenever new versions of byebug (and it's dependent libraries) are released.  It usually boils down to the thread running the app being paused when byebug (or pry) interrupts the test.  You can try rolling back to a previous version of byebug and/or listing out the threads at the byebug prompt and resuming the one that's running the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `sleep 10` on the byebug console.

The browser can only be "driven" by one process, calling sleep releases chromedriver's grip on the browser (for the length of the sleep period) so you can use the Web Inspector or click elements.

Comment: This works. https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/193 is one issue (going from 2016 to 2017, off and on) that describes the source of the problem, probably. I guess it's hanging in the blocking I/O syscall that waits for user input. Probably it would help if they switched to `IO.select` based I/O or whatever, with small `sleep` calls inbetween, instead of the `readline` call they are using. OTOH, it would just be nice if the `readline` would do this on its own...

Comment: This isn't "releasing chromedrivers grip" (in fact it has nothing whatsoever to do with chromedriver) it's just that when you call `sleep` in byebug it unpauses all the threads byebug paused for the period of the sleep, thereby reenabling the thread that's running the application under test so requests can be processed.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole given who you are you should of course know better than me. I was just under the impression that the issue had to do with [this behaviour](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2228#issuecomment-224316996) of the Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol and was paraphrasing the linked answer sloppily.